# Differentiate the first 2 characters in the strings of 2 different python lists

Tags: python

I would like to compare the first 2 letters in each of the strings in order to compare 2 lists. Given

```py
list1=['dog','cat','chicken']
list2=['drew','car','table']
```

How do I check if the first 2 letters in each of the strings in the lists are equal?

Comment: What does "the first alphabet" mean?  Do you mean the first _letter_ of each _word_ in the lists?

Comment: yes the first 2 letters in each of the strings

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward. Zip the two lists together to get pairs of corresponding words from each list, and then compare them to ensure all meet your criteria.

```
>>> list1=['dog','cat','chicken']
>>> list2=['drew','car','table']
>>> all(x[:2] == y[:2] for x, y in zip(list1, list2))
False
```

Comment: Please I want it to be true or false for each of the strings. For example dog and drew will be false, cat and car will be true, chicken and table will be false and so on.

Comment: Then use a list comprehension on the results of zipping the lists together instead of passing a generator expression to `all`.

Comment: Please I'm not really sure about how to do that. Thanks

Comment: The inside of the `all` produces a list of booleans, as you ask.  `all` merely asks "are all of these things true?"

Answer (score 0):

We can use the [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to iterate the values in both lists at the same time, and use string slicing inside a for loop to compare the first two characters of each pair:

```
list_a = ['dog', 'cat', 'chicken']
list_b = ['drew', 'car', 'table']

all_match = True
for word_a, word_b in zip(list_a, list_b):
    if word_a[:2] != word_b[:2]:
        print(f'The following words do not match in their first two characters: {word_a} - {word_b}')
        all_match = False
        break
    
if all_match:
    print('All word pairs match in their first two characters.')
```

Edit:
Seeing that you want to get the results as a list of boolean values, an easy modification to the above is:

```
list_a = ['dog', 'cat', 'chicken']
list_b = ['drew', 'car', 'table']
results = []

for word_a, word_b in zip(list_a, list_b):
    results.append(word_a[:2] == word_b[:2])
```

Expressed as one line using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list_a = ['dog', 'cat', 'chicken']
list_b = ['drew', 'car', 'table']

results = [a[:2] == b[:2] for (a, b) in zip(list_a, list_b)]
```